# Get list of user likes and reaction from facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to get the user id of those that 'likes' and 'react' to a posts(post not belonging to me). I notice that from the graph api explorer, likes and reactions are *greyed* out. Any advise if I can get those details?

Thanks.
Jeff

[image: fb graph api]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90-pages

> /page/* — User information will not be included in GET responses for any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a Page access token. This affects all nodes and edges that return data for objects owned by a Page.

In other words: If you don´t own the Page where the Post belongs to, it´s impossible to get user data.

Comment: Thanks lusch, but the post is a public data. I can see the likes and reaction, is there any alternative to obtain it? Need some advice, I am new in this. Thanks

Comment: that does not matter. pages are always public. there is no way to get user data anymore, if you do not own the page. "public on facebook.com" does not automatically mean you can get it.